# To find number of roots in interval $(1,2)$

Tags: calculus, polynomials

To find number of roots in interval $(1,2)$

$$f(x)= 3x^2 - 12x + 11 + \frac{x^3-6x^2+11x-6}{5} $$

Now $f(1)f(2)<0$. So it has one root. But how do I know whether it has two or three or whatever. Is there a general rule for these questions where we cannot explicitely find out the roots.

Comment: If it has three zeros, then its derivative has at least two zeros in $(1,2)$

Comment: You could derive f and see where the critical points are.

Comment: @Michael derivative has no zeroes in (1,2). What next ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there isn't a lot you can do when you are looking for roots of a function. However, in your case, $f$ is a polynomial, and its derivative is a second-degree polynomial.

That means you can easily find the roots of $f'$, meaning you can plot a rough sketch of $f$. You will discover that one local extrem (the minimum) of $f$ is just slightly right of number $2$. Because $f\to\infty$ as $x\to\infty$, you therefore know that one more root must be to the right of this minimum, therefore also to the right of $2$.

Thhe local maximum is far in the negative. Apply similar logic as before.

Comment: derivative of f is $3x^2+18x-49$. what should i do next?

Comment: @TaylorTed See the second part of my answer

Comment: No i donot understand

Comment: @TaylorTed Which part do you not understand?

Comment: roots of derivative are not in (1,2)

Comment: @TaylorTed Read my answer. From start to finish. Slowly. Then explain to me which part of the explanation I gave you is confusing to you. Just writing random true statements with no explanation about what you are thinking about is completely unproductive.

Comment: second paragraph third line

Comment: @TaylorTed I am deleting my answer. You obviously have no real desire to learn. Your answers consist of 5 words which you then expect I will decrypt and magically discover what you want to know. I won't play that game. If you are so lazy you can't even write 2 sentences "You say *this and this*, but I do not understand why this is so?", I will not help you.

Comment: Why one root is to be right of 2

Comment: @TaylorTed Well, what are the roots?

Comment: $-3 + 2 \sqrt 57/3$

Comment: @TaylorTed There you go. That number is greater than $2$.

Comment: So there is only one root in (1,2) of f

Comment: @TaylorTed Yes,

Comment: So a general rule is that if derivative of f has no root in (a,b) then f also has no root in it. am i right?

Comment: @TaylorTed No, If $f$ has no root in $(a,b)$, then $f$ has **at most one** root in $(a,b)$, It can have one or zero roots.

Answer (score 2):

Edit : My answer is about polynomials only.

You have Descartes'rule of signs (not exactly what you want but a first result) :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs

And if you want to go further you have Sturm's theorem which allows you to count the number of real roots of a real polynomial in an interval, see :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm's_theorem

Of course, in your particular case you could explicitely compute the derivative, its sign and then draw the curve by hand to check if you have one or three roots...

Comment: derivative of f is $3x^2+18x-49$. what should i do next?

Comment: @TaylorTed Compute its sign.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer is *Sturm's algorithm*. It is based on a sequence of Euclidean divisions. Here is a short description:

Consider the sequence of polynomials (*Sturm's sequence*) defined by:

- $f_0(x)=f(x)\enspace(\deg f=n),\quad f_1(x)=f'(x),$
- $f_{i-1}(x)=q_i(x)f_i(x)\boldsymbol{\color{red}{-}} f_{i+1}(x)$

  and  for all $a\in\mathbf R$ which is not a root of $f(x)$, set 
  $$\sigma(a)=\quad \text{number of sign changes in the sequence}\quad
  \bigl(f(a),f_1(a),\dots, f_n(a)\bigr)$$
  ($0$ is not counted as a sign change).
  The the number of real roots between $a$ and $b\enspace a<b$ is equal to
  $$\sigma(a)-\sigma(b).$$

**An elementary solution:**
Set $g(x)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6$. Then $f(x)=g'(x)+\frac15g(x)$, hence

- $f'(x)=g''(x)+\frac15g'(x)=6x-12+\frac15(3x^2-12x+11)$
- $f''(x)=g'''(x)+\frac15g''(x)=6+\frac15(6x-12)=\frac65(x+3)$

Hence $f'(x)$ has a minimum at $x=-3$ and $f'(-3)=6+\frac15(27+36+11)>0$, which implies the cubic polynomial $f$ has only $1$ real root.